# CLR classes redundancy

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, class, clr

is there any document or an article that describes differences between similar classes of .net, or classes that have different meanings but same names, or those that have different names but do almost the same thing?

for example:
When should we use `System.Timers.Timer` vs  `System.Threading.Timer`?

or what's the difference btw `System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException` and `System.TimeoutException`?

Sometimes you don't even know that you've been using something that actually considered "old" and "archaic" and you should use some better class instead, that was introduced in a new version of .net.

Can you please give more examples. It would be great to know all these kind of classes.

Comment: Way too broad & multiple questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, probably because "similar classes" is just not a good enough basis for a document or article (I'm just speculating here).

However, for specific issues - you will find articles.
Google "timers in .NET" and you'll find this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) explaining the difference between the three timers the framework offers.

Comment: +1. No. This information is in the specific documentation for each class, or set of classes. For example they will be marked "deprecated" or "obsolete" if you are supposed to use a new version. And thank heavens Microsoft did it that way. Can you imagine the chaos otherwise? Every time you wanted to use a class, as well as reading the specific documentation, you'd have to check some separate list of redundant classes?? Nightmare